# Careers profile Experience Screen

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, user-interface, firefox

On [Careers Profile Page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) during adding my experiences when I click the display options it show the overlapped field as:

> [image: careers]

I am using, windows 7, firefox 22 resolution 1368*768

Comment: Make sure zoom level is normal/100%.

Comment: tested.... it exist on 100%

Comment: Cannot reproduce this using the current version of Firefox.